# Error when trying to create an user with JWTAuth in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm trying to make a simple auth API to get tokens with JWTAuth with PHP and Laravel, but I get this error every time when I try to create a user:

```
[Tue Oct  6 07:21:21 2020] 127.0.0.1:56819 Accepted
[Tue Oct  6 07:21:22 2020] 127.0.0.1:56819 Closing
[Tue Oct  6 07:21:31 2020] 127.0.0.1:56820 Accepted
[Tue Oct  6 07:21:31 2020] PHP Fatal error:  Class App\Models\User contains 1 abstract method and must
 therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject::getJWTCustomClaims) 
in E:\_Code\laravel\ApiDevBarber\app\Models\User.php on line 10
[Tue Oct  6 07:21:33 2020] 127.0.0.1:56820 Closing
```

This error throws at both Insomnia, Rest test test, and Advanced REST client. I've followed the Laravel's and JWT documentation to write the User.php, below is the entire code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $hidden = ['password'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getkey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClains() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I'm new at PHP and Laravel, am I missing something?

Comment: Rename your method `getJWTCustomClains` to `getJWTCustomClaims`

Comment: I don't believe ... lol. I reviewed the code and skipped this typo, it must be because I'm not a native english speaker. Thanks @Dmitry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your method getJWTCustomClaims (and not getJWTCustomClains)

Comment: we usually don't write answers for simple typos, a comment and a close vote (caused by typo) is sufficient.